# Texture turns to gray in opengl when added alpha channel manually

Tags: opengl, textures, transparent, alpha, texture-mapping

```
int j,k,t3,t4;
for (int i = 0;i < width;i++)
    for (j = 0;j < height;j++)
    {
        t3 = (i*height + j)*3 ;
        t4 = (i*height + j) * 4;
        for (k = 0;k < 3;k++)
            texture[t4+k] = data[t3+k];
        texture[t4 + 3] = (data[t3 + 1]==255 && data[t3 + 2]==255 && data[t3]==255) ? 0 : 255;
    }


GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture);
```

It's a Bitmap file and I loaded it successfully with the original data.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

But when I added the Alpha channel manually the texture losts its color.The picture is attached below. [image: After modification on texture data.]
[image: Before Transparency is added.]

Comment: how are texture and data defined?

Comment: @BDL                                                                                                                      data = new unsigned char[imageSize];
 unsigned char *texture = new unsigned char[imageSize * 2];                       data is the raw 24bit image data read from a bitmap file while texture is the modified data, I attached an alpha channel after every BGR data by the loop in the first block of code.

Comment: @BillSun: BMP files are typically stored with a row alignment of 4 bytes, and OpenGL by default expects data in this format. Your code transforiming the data does not take such an alignment into account when accessing the source data. (The destination will always be aligned when you use 4 bytes per pixel, so that will not be an issue).

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite explain the exact symptoms, but the index arithmetic in your code looks off:

```
for (int i = 0;i < width;i++)
    for (j = 0;j < height;j++)
    {
        t3 = (i*height + j)*3 ;
        t4 = (i*height + j) * 4;
```

Since images are normally laid out in memory row by row, the index that iterates over the pixels in the row should be the one added without a multiplier, while the other index is multiplied by `width` (not `height`). This should be:

```
for (j = 0; j < height; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        t3 = (j * width + i) * 3;
        t4 = (j * width + i) * 4;
```